# text-transform capitalize css not working correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I've noticed a very strange problem when trying to style the navigation elements using the "text-transform: capitalize" css in my react project. It seems that React only applies the style to the first anchor tag and ignore the rest. However, everything works correctly with value set to "lowercase" or "uppercase".

Is this a known bug or it is intended?

here is the [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/embed/l4lnmvznvm) to demostrate the Problem

[image: Edit l4lnmvznvm]

Comment: seems to work fine - https://codesandbox.io/s/3r1zq85p9q

Comment: How are you applying the styles?

Comment: @ZoltanToth The problem only occurs when I try to style the anchor tag that is wrapped inside <NavLink> or <Link>.

Comment: @jens I used external css to apply the style. However, I tried applying the style directly inside javascript, it doesnt seem to work either. Please see the codepen that i added to the original post.

Comment: It looks like it's a browser bug. I only tested it in FF and Chrome and they both have it, which makes me suspect Safari and Edge have it, too. I've filed the bug with Chromium, which will most likely push a fix to Blink, which will eventually fix it in all the above browsers, sooner or later. Congrats on the find! I also came up with a workaround. Cheers!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Update

*(and correct answer - what's below the line is only left as reference, providing context to the discussion on Chromium forum, as [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=831901) was initially posted as a browser bug)*.

Although it might look like a bug, the implementation is correct. It's a feature. In short, any `display:inline` element is a *"letter"* in document's flow. If you decide not to put any space (or anything that might be interpreted as a space) between your letters, `text-transform:capitalize` should only capitalize the first letter in your *"word"*.

To fix it, either give your links `display:inline-block` or add a pseudo (`:before` or `:after`) with `display:inline-block;content:'';`

---

#### Previous update:

**TL,DR;**

```
nav a:before {
  content: '​'; /* copy-paste a zero-width-space (&#8203;) character */
}
```

... or simply prefixing your anchor texts with `&#8203;` seems to fix the problem.
But, to be clear about it, the above is a hack. A workaround.

Another fix is to set `nav a`'s display property to anything except `inline`, which is default  — yes, `display:none;` fixes it, too. For good! ツ...
...which leads to a third option, even less intrusive and not needing chars playing *hard-to-get*:

```
nav a:before {
  content: ''; /* empty string, no specials here */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Also works if used on `nav a:after`, if you need the `:before`s. What fixes it is breaking the continuous `inline` flow of the line.

---

**Updated answer:**

It looks like you found yourself a bug, which is currently present in both Chrome and Firefox. I haven't yet tested other browsers, but I'm expecting to experience this in the other webkit based browsers (Safari, Edge, Opera). I've filed the bug with [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=831901) which will, most likely, produce a fix for it in Chrome and, after a short while, in Firefox.

As suspected before you added the mcve, it's not related to React. I can reproduce it here, using simple markup:

```css
nav a {
   margin: 1em;
   text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div><nav><a href="/">home</a><a href="/2">page 2</a><a href="/3">page 3</a></nav><div>
```

The most weird thing about it is... if you place each element on a different line (in markup)... it starts working properly, without any other change.

```css
nav a {
   margin: 1em;
   text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div><nav><a href="/">home</a>
<a href="/2">page 2</a>
<a href="/3">page 3</a></nav><div>
```

Which led me to try out adding a zero-width-space `&#8203;` at the start of each anchor which, apparently, also **fixes the problem**:

```css
nav a {
  margin: 1em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
nav a:before {
  content: '​';
}
```

```html
<div><nav><a href="/">home</a><a href="/2">page 2</a><a href="/3">page 3</a></nav><div>
```

To apply the fix to your example, place this line before your `<nav>`:

```
<style>nav a:before{'{'}content:'&#8203;'{'}'}</style>
```

---

But still, it's a standing bug in Chrome <strike>and should be reported on their forum (and fixed)</strike>.

---

<strike>**Initial answer** (before seeing the example)</strike>

React is JavaScript.

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

... is CSS. If React handled it, the text would have been transformed before being placed in markup. The whole point of `text-transform` is to have the text unchanged in markup and rendered (by browser) transformed.

So your issue is not really a bug, and has nothing to do with React. It has to do with your browser not having implemented `text-transform:capitalize` yet. Or not applying it correctly.

See compatibility table [here](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/text/) and [here](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/text/). Unfortunatelly, it's hard to determine (other than by trying them out yourself) browser support for a particular value of a partially supported property.

Until your browser supports it, you'll have to use React (or vanilla) or the library of your choice (i.e.: lodash has [_.capitalize()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#capitalize)) to capitalize your text.

And this simple example will tell you if your current browser supports it:

```css
capitalize-meh {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<capitalize-meh>i should be capitalized...</capitalize-meh>
```

The only way to "fix" this in browser that don't have CSS support for `capitalize` is to define your own function:

```
capitalize(string) {
  return string.toLowerCase().replace(/(^|\s)\S/g, l => l.toUpperCase())
}
```

Test:

```js
class TextExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.text = props.text || '';
  }

  capitalize(string) {
    return string.toLowerCase().replace(/(^|\s)\S/g, l => l.toUpperCase())
  }

  render() {
    return (<text>{this.capitalize(this.text)}</text>);
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  new TextExample({text:'what eVaH...'}).render(),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: My apology that I wasn't being very clear with my question. My browser is fine, I've updated my post to provide more info about my project set up.

Comment: Hi @Andrei, I've created a codepen to demonstrate the issue, please have a look https://codesandbox.io/embed/l4lnmvznvm

Answer (score -2):

Use `uppercase` instead of `capitalize`

```
.myclass
{
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```